# How can I remove logback from a library's dependency while keeping SLF4J?

Tags: java, maven, logging, dependencies, slf4j

In my Vaadin project, I have a dependency on a certain library. This library uses slf4j for logging. In the library pom, logback slf4j binding is added as a runtime dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In my application, I directly use log4j for logging. I want the logs added by the library to go in my log4j log.

For this, I added following to my pom to include slf4j log4j binding

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, slf4j complains that it has found multiple bindings.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/program_files/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/temp/0-ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/program_files/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/temp/0-ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

I checked the dependency tree of my application, which has following for its dependency on logback. (Following is the only dependency on logback)

```
[INFO] |  +- com.mycompany.mylib:libname:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.13:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.13:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-access:jar:1.0.13:runtime
```

Also, when I checked inside `WEB-INF\lib` directory in my war file, I found following jars.

```
logback-access-1.0.13.jar
logback-classic-1.0.13.jar
logback-core-1.0.13.jar
```

Why did logback ended up in my lib directory? As I have heard, runtime dependencies should not come into libs directory.

How should I resolve this? The library is developed within my company and I can ask the library developers to remove the logback runtime dependencies if needed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Option 1: They change their pom.

The easiest way to fix this would be to have the library developers in your own company mark logback as **optional** and require SLF4J as a compile dependency explicitly. This is the *right, canonical* way to do SLF4J in Maven. In other words:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>${logback.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

---

#### Option 2: You revise their dependencies in your pom.

If you want to fix it yourself, without going through them, then you can use the **`exclusions`** tag when declaring their dependency. In other words, in your pom, do:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>your.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>libraryname</artifactId>
    <version>${theirlibrary.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

---

You asked if there's an reason to depend on Logback directly; generally there isn't, for a library author. Their pom configuration is probably just a minor oversight on their part. There are some reasons to depend on logback specifically, but they have to do with startup (stuff with [`JoranConfigurator`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/joran/JoranConfigurator.html) or [`StatusPrinter`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/util/StatusPrinter.html), that sort of thing, which shouldn't come up with a library. Other reasons to call Logback classes directly include stuff like [custom appenders](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html), which, again, shouldn't come up in a library, only a deployed app.

Comment: Tried your second option and it works. Can you please tell me whether there is a legitimate reason for the library developers to include logback dependency in their pom? I checked their code and they do not use any logback functionality directly.

Comment: Unfortunately logback itself comes as "the logger" as well "the slf4j binding" all in one so sometimes library makers include it without realizing they should make it optional :|